# Where to put liquibase.properties file when using org.springframework.boot?

Tags: liquibase

I'm getting error trying to use local XSD file in changelog.xml (new security feature was introduced in ver 4.8)

> Failed to read schema document 'dbchangelog-4.12.xsd', because 'file'
> access is not allowed due to restriction set by the
> accessExternalSchema property.

I know, that I need to create liquibase.properties file in the liquibase directory with

```
secureParsing="false"
accessExternalSchema="all"
```

but the question is: where to put this liquibase.properties file and how to make it work if liquibase is not installed on my Mac computer?
I created this file and placed it in every folder of my project, but it does not work.
Docker container builds this way:

```
mvn clean install -f pom.xml
docker build -t ${APP}:${VER} --build-arg APP=${APP} --build-arg VER=${VER} --build-arg JARSRC=${JARSRC} -f Dockerfile .
```

changelog.xml

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                          dbchangelog-4.12.xsd"
    objectQuotingStrategy="QUOTE_ONLY_RESERVED_WORDS">
```

POM.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <relativePath/> 
        </parent>
    
 <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <javax.validation.api.version>2.0.1.Final</javax.validation.api.version>
    <liquibase.version>4.12.0</liquibase.version>
    <hibernate-validator.version>6.2.1.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
    <javax.el.version>3.0.0</javax.el.version>
    <javax.jms.version>2.0.1</javax.jms.version>
    <google.libphonenumber.version>8.12.51</google.libphonenumber.version>
    <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.24</org.projectlombok.version>
    <build.helper.maven.plugin.version>3.3.0</build.helper.maven.plugin.version>
    <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0-M7</maven.surefire.version>
    <maven.surefire.plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
    <maven.failsafe.plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</maven.failsafe.plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
       <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
       <version>${javax.validation.api.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
       <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
       <version>${javax.el.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
       <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
       <version>${google.libphonenumber.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
       <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
       <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
       <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
       <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
       <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
       <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
       <artifactId>surefire-api</artifactId>
       <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
       <version>${javax.jms.version}</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
       <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
       <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
    
<build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
               <mainClass>gov.va.dgi.DgiJavaInstitutionManagerServiceApplication</mainClass>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
           <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>${build.helper.maven.plugin.version}</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>add-integration-test-source</id>
                   <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <sources>
                           <source>src/integration-test/java</source>
                       </sources>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
           <configuration>
               <skipTests>false</skipTests>
               <excludes>
                   <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest</exclude>
                   <exclude>**/*IT</exclude>
               </excludes>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
   <profile>
       <id>failsafe</id>
       <build>
           <testResources>
               <testResource>
                   <directory>src/integration-test/resources</directory>
               </testResource>
           </testResources>
           <plugins>
<!-- when running failsafe integration tests, we do not want to run regular unit tests-->
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                   <configuration>
                       <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                       <excludes>
                           <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest</exclude>
                           <exclude>**/*IT</exclude>
                       </excludes>
                   </configuration>
               </plugin>
    
               <plugin>
                   <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>${maven.failsafe.plugin.version}</version>
                   <executions>
                       <execution>
                           <goals>
                               <goal>integration-test</goal>
                               <goal>verify</goal>
                           </goals>
                       </execution>
                   </executions>
                   <configuration>
 <!-- for int tests, remove H2 so @SpringBootTest and @DataJpaTests don't switch the db -->
                       <classpathDependencyExcludes>
                                 <classpathDependencyExclude>com.h2database:h2</classpathDependencyExclude>
                       </classpathDependencyExcludes>
                   </configuration>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
        </build>
     </profile>
   </profiles>
    
 </project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a new feature, we need a PR to investigate. Please [submit a bug report.](https://www.liquibase.org/community/contribute/report-bugs)

Comment: Just for reference: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/3072 (not filed by me)